# react-native-maps custom map style

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I created a json using google maps styling wizard. I then set that to a const under render and set that const to my MapView style but it renderers nothing when I do.

I am not sure the issue, Ideally I would like to have the style in a separate file but I was trying to start small.

**How can I fix the current issue I am having as well as import and use the style from a separate file?**

Here is a [snack of my code](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/custom-map-style) that reproduces my exact error as well as the code below.

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {

 
  render() {
    const mapStyle = [
      {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.attraction",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "on"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.government",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

    return (
     <View style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}>
      <MapView
        style={mapStyle}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}>
      </MapView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom google maps styling must be passed to the `customMapStyle` prop and you need to set a specific `width` and `height` in the normal `style` prop of the `MapView`. Setting `absoluteFillObject` does something different than you might have thought and according to the [react-native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#absolutefill-vs-absolutefillobject) there is

> Currently, there is no difference between using absoluteFill vs. absoluteFillObject.

Thus, `absoluteFill` is for the following use case.

> A very common pattern is to create overlays with position absolute and zero positioning (position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0), so absoluteFill can be used for convenience and to reduce duplication of these repeated styles.

This will **not set a height and a width**! We need to do this manually which is documented [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps).

The following solves your problem.

```js
const styles = ScaledSheet.create({
  map: {
width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    
  },
...
```

The JSX component.

```js
return (
     <View style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}>
      </MapView>

      </View>
    );
```

Here is the full solution.

```js
export default class Map extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const mapStyle = [
      {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.attraction",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "on"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.government",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    
    return (
     <View style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}>
      </MapView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = ScaledSheet.create({
  map: {
width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    
  },
  bubble: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 15,
  },
  carousel: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: scale(625)
  },
  cardContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
    height: scale(40),
    width: scale(300),
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  name: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 22,

  }
});
```

Defining the `customMapStyle` in a separate file is plain JS and can be done as follows.

Define a new file, named `CustomMapStyle.js` and add the following content.

```js
export const CustomMapStyle = [
      {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.attraction",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "on"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.government",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Then use it as follows.

```js
import {CustomMapStyle} from './CustomMapStyle'

...

render() {    
    return (
     <View style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        customMapStyle={CustomMapStyle}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}>
      </MapView>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

I have updated [your snack here](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/custom-map-style).

The final result.

[image]

Comment: So the absoluteFill was the issue... Thanks David. You are becoming my React Native tutor at this point... Will award the bounty in 12 hours when it is available!

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad to help! I actually learn a lot myself by answering questions. It's a win-win!

Comment: I cannot seem to find any examples online regarding changing the style of maps via a button...do you have any idea as to how to go about this? As you can imagine... I would like to be able to change the map style along with the dark theme we recently talked about :)

Comment: I am glad to hear that David!

Comment: This might be a bit more difficult in comparison with normal components. See [this question on GitHub](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/1254). In summary, we can change the `customMapStyle` prop using the theme state as before, but we have to remount the MapView component. According to this issue, this can be done automatically by changing the `key` prop which could be just the theme as string, I suppose.

Comment: I am gonna do my best... hopefully you wont see this as a question going into the weekend. Thanks again David!